# JS scope issue: How can I reuse the locations data in this script?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this pretty long script which is right now using a second AJAX call to fetch the data as a temporary Workaround.

Where there suggestion call is made `/admin/locations/suggest.json` the result is an array of objects. A list is displayed with the data from these objects. When one of them is clicked a second AJAX call is made to `/admin/locations/view/' + locationId + '.json` to fetch the location data - again. This data is already there but in the data that was returned from the first AJAX call.

My issue is now accessing the Locations variable from inside the on.click() code. I've already got the index there and everything but `locations` doesn't have the data present.

How can I populate the `locations` after my first call and use them in the on.click() event?

```
SuggestLocation = function() {
    var locations = null;
    $('#NewLocation').hide();

    function suggestLocation(locations) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/locations/suggest.json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#AgendaItemAdminAddForm, #AgendaItemAdminEditForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var htmlString = '';
                for (var p in data.data) {
                    htmlString = htmlString + '<li data-index="' + p + '" data-id="' + data.data[p].Location.id + '">' + data.data[p].Location.display_name + '</li>';
                }
                $('#LocationSuggestions').html(htmlString);
                locations = data.data;
                console.log(locations);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    };
    $(document).on('click', '#LocationSuggestions li', function(event) {
        locationIndex = ($(this).data('index'));
        locationId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/locations/view/' + locationId + '.json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: null,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#SelectedLocation').html(
                    Mustache.render($('#LocationTemplate').html(), data.data)
                );
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
        $('#AgendaItemLocationId').val(locationId);
        $('#AgendaItemLocationId').val(locationId);
        $('#LocationFormFields').hide();
        $('#LocationSuggestions').html('');
        $('#NewLocation').show();
    });
    $('#LocationFormFields input, #LocationFormFields textarea').keydown(function() {
        suggestLocation();
    });
    $('#LocationFormFields select').change(function () {
        suggestLocation();
    });
    $('#NewLocation').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#AgendaItemLocationId').val($(this).data(''));
        $('#LocationFormFields').show();
        $('#SelectedLocation').hide();
        suggestLocation();
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
};
SuggestLocation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

```
var locations = null;
```

creates *locations* in the outer scope (the assignment of *null* is redundant, it does nothing useful), however when you do:

```
function suggestLocation(locations) {
```

that creates a *locations* variable that is local to *suggestLocation*, so later when you do:

```
  locations = data.data;
```

the data is assigned to that *locations* variable, not the outer one. None of the calls to *suggestLocation* pass a parameter to the function, so simply get rid of *locations* as a formal parameter, i.e. make it:

```
function suggestLocation() {
```

so the value is assigned to the outer *locations* that is available to all functions within *SuggestLocation*.

Just remember that the AJAX call is asynchronous so make sure the callback has been called and the value assigned before you try to access it.

Also, function names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors so *SuggestLocation* is not appropriate. Nor is it a good idea to have two functions whose name is identical except for the capitalisation of a single letter.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to remove it from the function call while I was messing around with it. By convention: What convention? Is there some official coding convention for ECMA script or Jquery?

Comment: Official? No, but there are published examples, like Douglas Crockford's [*Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language*](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and the [*Google JavaScript Style Guide*](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), which both just *happen* to support that particular convention. ;-)